# How to find a value bigger than zero and write the corespondent column name in a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below:

```
 M1 M2T M2N FOKI    LOESS   PYRIT   ABRAUM  AV  DEP_TON DEP_TON_15  FOKIFE  FOKIMA  KIES
 0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5755
 0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1284
 0  0   2084    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 4471   2922    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 0  0   0   0   0   19522   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I would like to create a new column and the value of this for each row is the column name of the row that has a value bigger than zero like this:

```
 MaterialType   M1  M2T M2N FOKI    LOESS   PYRIT   ABRAUM  AV  DEP_TON DEP_TON_15  FOKIFE  FOKIMA  KIES
 KIES   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5755
 KIES   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1284
 M2N    0   0   2084    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 M1-M2T 4471    2922    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 PYRIT  0   0   0   0   0   19522   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

for the rows that have >1 values, seperated by dash.

Could you please to help me to write a small script in pandas python?

Thanks :)

Comment: /@Masoud, what have you tried?

Comment: I have no clue actually :(

Comment: This forum offers help with coding, does not write for other people... Visit this site and learn, Post your idea above.  https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Comment: /@Masoud, most people give a try to coding the problem... it looks like you havent even tried...We all started somewhere. --at zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find values higher as `0` and multiple this mask with column names:

```
print ((df > 0) * df.columns.to_series())
   M1  M2T  M2N FOKI LOESS  PYRIT ABRAUM AV DEP_TON DEP_TON_15 FOKIFE FOKIMA  \
0                                                                              
1                                                                              
2           M2N                                                                
3  M1  M2T                                                                     
4                           PYRIT                                              

   KIES  
0  KIES  
1  KIES  
2        
3        
4
```

Then concanecate all values by `join` and remove starts and end `-` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['new'] = (((df > 0) * df.columns.to_series()).apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1 )
                                                .str.strip('-'))
print (df)


     M1   M2T   M2N  FOKI  LOESS  PYRIT  ABRAUM  AV  DEP_TON  DEP_TON_15  \
0     0     0     0     0      0      0       0   0        0           0   
1     0     0     0     0      0      0       0   0        0           0   
2     0     0  2084     0      0      0       0   0        0           0   
3  4471  2922     0     0      0      0       0   0        0           0   
4     0     0     0     0      0  19522       0   0        0           0   

   FOKIFE  FOKIMA  KIES     new  
0       0       0  5755    KIES  
1       0       0  1284    KIES  
2       0       0     0     M2N  
3       0       0     0  M1-M2T  
4       0       0     0   PYRIT
```

Comment: It was definitely helpful. just small question, the output of str.join can be like this, HKN----HKT, if the columns aren't next to each other, I tried str.replace(...) or str.translate(...), but I those doesn't work.

Comment: I think you can add it to `'----'.join(x)'`

Comment: your recommendation doesn't work. I tried "'-'.join(set(x))" and it worked ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I dont test it. Nice day. Glad can help you!